# applescript to invoke alt keypress on cmd+tap keypress to switch to hidden window without physically pressing alt

Tags: macos, applescript

I've hated the fact that I have to use the alt key to cmd+tab to hidden windows ever since I switched to MAC.
I know there are apps ( like [witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) ) that replace the cmd+tab function but I like the current interface I don't want to change that. besides that I just want to build the apple script for it :)

So here is what I want to create:

when I press `cmd+tap` -> keydown `alt`

Then when I then release `cmd` it should release the `alt` key.

The result would be I never have to press the alt key again when switching to 'hidden' windows. Much like other OS systems.

But it looks to me like all apple scripts start with `tell application`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't posible to detect key presses by the user in applescript. You can press keys programmatically though. To solve your problem of holding down a key use the "key down" command and issue the "key up" command when you need to release it. That will work in any application. Here's an example.

```
tell application "KeyboardViewer" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    try --don't even consider not using a try block because down keys can get stuck!
        key down control
        delay 1
        key down shift
        delay 1
        key down option
        delay 1
        key down command
        delay 1
        key up control
        delay 1
        key up shift
        delay 1
        key up option
        delay 1
        key up command
        delay 1
        key down {control, shift, option, command}
        delay 1
        key up {control, shift, option, command}
    on error --logging out is the only other way to unstick these
        key up {control, shift, option, command}
    end try
end tell
tell application "KeyboardViewer" to quit
```

NOTE: you could also use the "keystroke" command if you wanted to sequentially press and release some keys. For example to press command-s you could do the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "s" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try it tomorrow and accept this answer is it works. looks very logical though but I got to go right now.

Comment: Try this in its place. I'm on 10.8 but on earlier versions it was called this... KeyboardViewerServer.app.

Comment: I'm using 10.8.2, but maybe I'm building it wrong? I'm using the AppleScript Editor

Comment: I'm on 10.8.2 too and you can find KeyboardViewer in "/System/Library/Input Methods" folder. In any case, the code will work as I've shown. The KeyboardViewer is an app that displays a keyboard on your screen and you can see the key presses on that keyboard as the script is running. So I only included it to show you the system events part works. You don't need it. Try the system events code and see if it does what you need in your own code.

Comment: yes this does press the key's but how do I check if the key's are pressed buy the user (me)

Comment: Applescript can't watch the keyboard and alert you about the keys pressed by the user. You'd need objective-c for that.

Comment: Guess I have to start learning objective-c then... hmm then I'll just press the 'alt' key for now.